# IE6,7,8,9 loading div underneath another div while other browsers load it to the right

Tags: html, css

http://gainntrain.com/site/index-1.html

`<div class="grid_7 prefix_2 alpha omega">`

that div is loading underneath  `<div class="grid_15 omega">`

when it *should* be loading to the right of it as it does in chrome and firefox.

Now I did notice that the div does move to the right when I turn off "Compatibility mode" but then other things like the header get messed up when I turn off compatibility mode so that is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling IE to render in the old non-standard way, then you're confused as to why it doesn't render like the standard browsers do?

You're trying to use an old version of cufon that is incompatible with IE9, and then trying to hack it to make it work.

You're also trying to use HTML5 while also telling IE to use compatibility mode, that's also a recipe for disaster.

Use standards mode, update your cufon to 1.09i (which is IE9 compatible) or even better yet, just use @font-face, which is the standard way to do fonts (ie has supported this for ages).

Every javascript hack you add has the potential of conflicting with something else.  HTML5shiv is bad enough, that combined with cufon makes it almost impossible to debug your DOM.